# PowerShell Add-Content with Get-Service

Tags: windows, powershell, service, server

```
$Service = Get-Service -ComputerName SYNESIGNSVR -Name SynAutoImportService
$ServiceDName = $Service.DisplayName
$ServiceStat = $Service.Status

Add-Content "c:\temp\logtemp - Services Status.log" "$(Get-Date -Format 
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") - $ServiceDName service on server SYNESIGNSVR current 
status: $ServiceStat"
```

I am writing a PS script that will create a log file with several different services and their current status from a few different windows servers.  The above code works and returns:

> 2017-04-19 12:01:17 - Synergy Document AutoImport service on server SYNESIGNSVR current status: Running

This seems like sloppy code, the way I've pulled the Get-Service and made the Status and DisplayName pull in.

I'm looking for ways I could make this code cleaner and or more efficient.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Agreed, Ansgar.  I'm just a bit new with PowerShell and am looking for ways to optimize / write clean code.  This code does return what I want and need.

Comment: I meant that your code is fine the way it is. You could get the same result in different ways (see for instance TessellatingHeckler's answer), but I wouldn't consider either approach "cleaner" or "more efficient" than the other, at least not in the context of your question.

Comment: Makes since.  I see I do get the same results with TessellatingHeckler's example below but it's still a similar amount of code.

Comment: That's just because he's not formatting the date. You can easily fix that by changing `{0}` to `{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
$Computer = 'SYNESIGNSVR'
$Service = Get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -Name SynAutoImportService

$LogLine = "{0} - {1} service on server {2} current status: {3}" -f [DateTime]::Now,
                                                                    $Service.DisplayName,
                                                                    $Computer,
                                                                    $Service.Status

Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\logtemp - Services Status.log" -Value $LogLine
```

Comment: I would think wrap them into a function if it is frequently used, and take `Computer` `ServiceName` `logFile` as parameter, rest the same.

Comment: Also value for `Path` parameter would be better on the top of the script in variable e.g. $outputPath

Comment: Same for the logline template.

Comment: I'm unfamilar with creating functions.  I've just never made one myself.  Maybe I will do some research and look in to that option.

In my full script I do use a variable for the output path, I just didn't show it here.  Thanks for that suggestion pandemic

Comment: It's a 4 line script; everything is already at the top. :-/   I don't like the style of `$var = "thing";  $var` unless the variable is going to be used again. The intent of my splitting the LogLine out is to neatly format the parameters so it's not a busy three-line wraparound string, and doesn't need variables taking the property values needlessly. I don't see the benefit to splitting out the path and the message template into separate variables, or putting the code into a function, for something this small. Yes if the `Add-Content` is going to be 20 lines down, or called several times, etc.